# SQL Query to select customers who have already purchased all the items from their Wishlist

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to write a query and as it is a bit complex, I am not able to get the right results.

**Goal of the query:** Get list of Customer who have bought all the items from their Wishlist?

*I have 2 tables and the fields as given below,*

1. **Customer_Orders :** `Customer_ID`, `Order_ID`, `Order_date` , `Product_ID`, `email`
2. **Wishlist :** `Customer_ID`, `Created_Date` , `Product_ID`

I was only able to write the below query, which just checks the products customer has bought from Wishlist

```
select w.Customer_ID,w.Product_ID
from Wishlist w
inner join Customer_Orders od
on od.Product_ID=w.Prodcuct_ID and od.Customer_ID=w.Customer_ID
```

What I want instead is to fetch those customers(Customer_ID) who have bought all the items from their `Wishlist`.

Please can anyone help me know how the query should be ??

Comment: There is no counts in the tables. Imagine that wishlist contains a lot of rows for some product for some customer, and a lot of rows with the same product in orders. Maybe one row == one product item, and we must to compare the amount of rows in the tables? Or maybe (customer_id, product_id) is defined as unique in both tables?

Comment: @akina,thanks for the reply...yes customer_id, product_id is defined as unique in both the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> yes customer_id, product_id is defined as unique in both the tables – sfmc_newbie

```sql
SELECT Customer_ID
FROM Wishlist
LEFT JOIN Customer_Orders USING (Customer_ID, Product_ID)
GROUP BY Customer_ID
HAVING !SUM(Customer_Orders.Product_ID IS NULL)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=352142a37fd1aaddcc6d3c20ef886d30

Comment: @sfmc_newbie . . . You can use `HAVING COUNT(Customer_Orders.Product_ID) = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase this using aggregation by customer, then assert that the wishlist count is completely full:

```sql
SELECT w.Customer_ID
FROM Wishlist w
LEFT JOIN Customer_Orders od
    ON od.Product_ID = w.Product_ID AND od.Customer_ID = w.Customer_ID
GROUP BY w.Customer_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.Product_ID) = COUNT(DISTINCT od.Product_ID);
```

If the assertion in the `HAVING` clause fails for some customer, then it means that there exist one or more products in the wishlist which did *not* find a match in the customer orders table.

Comment: ?? COUNTs to be compared must be counted before joining - if not then they will be equal for all Product_ID values which are present in Customer_Orders for the customer.

Comment: @Akina No, they won't, because I'm doing a left join.  Should a given customer in the left side wishlist not match, then `COUNT(od.Product_ID)` would _not_ contribute to the count.  But yes, the count on the left would always be the same value.

Comment: Imagine you have 2 rows in Wishlist and 3 rows in Customer_Orders with the same Product_ID. You will have 6 rows after joining, and so both COUNTs will give 6.

Comment: My answer assumes (perhaps incorrectly) that a given relationship between product and customer would only occur once.

Comment: @Akina, I see nothing wrong (besides query perfomance may be) even in the case when the same item+customer  has multiple rows in both tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @tim . There is a possibility that the customer has bought the product from Wishlist more than once. Then will this query work?

Comment: Yes, it should work as I have updated to only consider the distinct product counts on both sides of the comparison.  Test the answer against your actual data to verify this.

Comment: Thanks a lot,,,,I will verify and get back

Answer (score 2):

Customers having no wishlist item not bought yet. NOT EXISTS version

```
SELECT distinct w.Customer_ID
FROM Wishlist w
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM Wishlist wc
                 WHERE wc.Customer_ID = w.Customer_ID
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                   FROM Customer_Orders od
                                   WHERE od.Product_ID = wc.Product_ID AND od.Customer_ID = wc.Customer_ID))
```

Comment: sorry i did not understand the above query correctly. I want to select customers who have purchased all the items from their Wishlist

Comment: @sfmc_newbie, yes, it does. Purchased all the items == exists no item which is not purchased.